# I cant get pagination to work on my search results page

Tags: php, html, search

I have created a search site where people can search for items by submitting a keywords and results are displayed onto a results page. I have been trying to make the search results page include pagination because I only want to display 10 results per page. I was wondering if anyone would know how to do this as all of the tutorials I have followed don't seem to work.

Here is the code used for my results page:

```
<?php

            $button = $_GET ['submit'];
            $search = $_GET ['search']; 

            if(!$button)
            echo "<p>Sorry but we can't find any results if you do not      submit a keyword</p>";
            else
            {
            if(strlen($search)<=1)
            echo "<p>Sorry but the search term you provided is too short for     us to find any items related.</p> ";
            else{
            echo "<p>You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br></p><p>If your site hasn't shown up just visit the Members area and submit it!</p>";
            mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
            mysql_select_db("database");

            $search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

            foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
            {
            $x++;
            if($x==1)
            $construct .="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
            else
            $construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

            }

            $construct ="SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct";
            $run = mysql_query($construct);

            $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

            if ($foundnum==0)
            echo "<p>Sorry, there are no matching results for     <b>$search</b>.</br></br>1. 
            Try more general words. for example: If you want to search 'how     to create a website'
            then use general keyword like 'create' 'website'</br>2. Try different words with similar
             meaning</br>3. Please check your spelling.</br>4. If you have any ideas on sites you want to show up submit it to our database.</p>";
            else
            {
            echo "<p>We found $foundnum results!</p>";

            while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
            {
            $title = $runrows ['title'];
            $desc = $runrows ['description'];
            $url = $runrows ['url'];

            echo "
            <p><a href='$url'><b>$title</b></a><br>
            $desc<br>
            <a href='$url'>$url</a></p>

            ";

            }
            }

            }
            }

            ?>
```

If anyone has any ideas that may help me then that would be amazing!

Thanks

Comment: carry your search term in either url or session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic way of building paginations are by using LIMIT and OFFSET.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 // Fetch 10 rows from table starting from row 0

SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 // Fetch the next 10 rows from the table. starting from row 20
```

So. Lets try the following:

```
$limit = 10;
$pageNum = ( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0 ? $_GET['page'] : 0 );
$offset = ($pageNum * $limit);


$construct ="SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE $construct ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " . $limit . " OFFSET " . $offset;



print '<a href="/search.php?search=' . $search . '&page=' . $pageNum+1 . '">Next page</a>
```

Generally i would like to warn you against using the old mySql drivers for Php, and inserting unsanitized data into the queries, directly from the client. But this is the basics, written into your own codestyle.

I would recommend you to have a look at PDO or MySqli, which both support prepared(kindof) statements for safer query-generation.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi, I had a go at adding your code to my search results page but when i click next page it deletes the search term that the person had put in from the form.

Comment: Hi James. Check it out now. I simply added the "search" query to the link, so that it follows.

Comment: @Jonasm how do you get back to the page? Next and Previous!